# Cocoa and caching

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to download a property list from a webserver using -initWithContentsOfURL

The problem I am having is that Cocoa caches the response from the webserver and so the file I am trying to download. This means that the first time it will work fine but the second time, the file on the server has changed, it won't work properly. It just "downloads" ( just copies it from the cache.db database ) the old file.

What is the best way to work around this? Would I have to implement something more "sophisticated" like NSURLDownload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the HTTP headers in the response?  Try this at the terminal:

```
curl -I http://the-uri-for-the-plist
```

It is possible the server is specifying that the file can be cached.

Comment: Cache-Control: max-age=315360000           nice one, I didn't even think about this at all. Time to break out htaccess